# XRDP client cant see task menu nor buttons (remote connection)

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm just curious if anyone had the problem of not being able to see any menu's or Ubuntu related gui buttons in a rdp instance with remote desktop software.

I was able to drag icons onto the desktop and view them - but other than that, nothing is viewable. im using a Windows 7 remote desktop connecting to Ubuntu. Other than this issue everything else runs very smoothly.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you relate to?

Answer (score 0):

[You need x11rdp whose binary is not included by default](http://scarygliders.net/2012/06/20/x11rdp-o-matic-and-rdpsesconfig-version-2/).

Great job Kevin!
Above link will allow you to compile from source.

I had the same issue, no menu or taskbar only the background and I tried ubuntu-2d and gnome-fallback. None of them worked. After installing `x11rdp` it worked like a charm.

After install, run your `RDPsesconfig.sh` and in remote desktop from Windows choose `sesman-X11rdp` instead of `sesman-vnc`. 32-bit color works for me fine with ubuntu 12.04.